# How could this SSO implementation possibly work without browser cookies?

Tags: authentication, cookies, chrome, sso

Our corporate Windows 7 desktop setup is now using SSO with our Confluence instance (browser-based wiki-type website) but the strangest thing is that even after logging out AND clearing the browser cookies (and everything else) I still remain signed-in!!??  This situation only happens when using Chrome.  With Firefox, when I log out (or clear cookies) I remain logged out.

When navigating to our Confluence URL, it first redirects to our corporate SSO domain, and then back to Confluence.  So, it's doing something to get my Windows credentials I guess, but I don't understand how it can sign me back in after I logged out of both the Confluence site AND the SSO site AND cleared cookies.  In fact, at this point, I cannot sign-out at all.

Is the behavior I described with the Chrome browser supposed to be happening and, if so, by what mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your web applications and/or your corporate SSO was setup to use SPNEGO authentication, which is most times used with Kerberos. It then uses your Kerberos ticket granting ticket (TGT) you obtained during Windows logon to get service tickets for authenticating to a "kerberized" service.

In the Windows browser configuration there are options IIRC called "Integrated Authentication".

There's also a tool called *kerbtray.exe* which displays current content of your Windows session's ticket cache. If SPNEGO/Kerberos is used you will find service tickets for service principal names like *HTTP/app.example.com@REALM.EXAMPLE.COM* or similar.

Comment: Thank you.  I found "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" in the Advanced tab of the Internet Properties of the Control Panel.